# SQL Email Job Failing after amending it

Tags: sql, t-sql, email, report

I currently have a SQL job that executes a list of all the users of a specific piece of software.

However, I now want to add the first name and last name together to make a complete name. I've created the simple SQL to handle such request but when I attempt to include it into the SQL JOB it fails:

Failure reason:

```
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102).  The step failed.
```

SQL JOB that's failing:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'test=email',
    @recipients = 'test@hotmail.co.uk',
    @subject = 'Users Report',
@body = '<b> Please follow the correct procedure (see other email)
@body_format = 'HTML',    
    @query = 'SELECT   [testDB].[dbo].[base_user].buser_userid  AS [N4 User ID]
            , [testDB].[dbo].[base_user].buser_firstName + ' ' +
           [testDB].[dbo].[base_user].buser_lastName as [Users Name]
            ,[testDB].[dbo].[sec_role].role_name  as [Role]
            ,[testDB].[dbo].[sec_role].role_description as [Description]
            ,[testDB].[dbo].[base_user].buser_active AS [Active?]
FROM      [testDB].[dbo].base_user
INNER JOIN [testDB].[dbo].[sec_user_role_map] ON testDB.dbo.base_user.[buser_gkey] = testDB.dbo.[sec_user_role_map].[usrrolm_user_gkey]
INNER JOIN [testDB].[dbo].[sec_role] ON testDB.dbo.[sec_user_role_map].[usrrolm_role_gkey] = testDB.[dbo].[sec_role].role_gkey

',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your single quotes on the CONCAT

Also you missed one on the end of the line `@body`

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'test=email',
    @recipients = 'test@hotmail.co.uk',
    @subject = 'Users Report',
@body = '<b> Please follow the correct procedure (see other email)',
@body_format = 'HTML',    
    @query = 'SELECT   [testDB].[dbo].[base_user].buser_userid  AS [N4 User ID]
            , [testDB].[dbo].[base_user].buser_firstName + '' '' +
           [testDB].[dbo].[base_user].buser_lastName as [Users Name]
            ,[testDB].[dbo].[sec_role].role_name  as [Role]
            ,[testDB].[dbo].[sec_role].role_description as [Description]
            ,[testDB].[dbo].[base_user].buser_active AS [Active?]
FROM      [testDB].[dbo].base_user
INNER JOIN [testDB].[dbo].[sec_user_role_map] ON testDB.dbo.base_user.[buser_gkey] = testDB.dbo.[sec_user_role_map].[usrrolm_user_gkey]
INNER JOIN [testDB].[dbo].[sec_role] ON testDB.dbo.[sec_user_role_map].[usrrolm_role_gkey] = testDB.[dbo].[sec_role].role_gkey

',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, that really helped. You sure know your stuff!